# Convert the parsed T&Z timestamp to millisecond

Tags: groovy, jmeter, beanshell, jsr223

1)  In response, a time stamp returned and is in T&Z format, ex: “2018-10-09T10:10:00Z”.

2)  I have parsed the date and saved in a variable(date1) using “Regular Expression Extractor”.

3)  In the successive request I would need to use the parsed time but this time I want to use it in millisecond format for the next request.

4)  Here is my sample snippet looks like in “BSF PreProcessor”,
Here “date1” is a variable to which the value is parsed and extracted using Regular Expression Extractor.

Code snippet,

```
var time1 = vars.get(date1);
var timem1 = new Date(time1);
var timem1 = timem1.getTime();
vars.put("timem1",timem1);
```

But the above code didn’t help.
Can anyone please help me here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the below;-

```
String b1 = "2018-10-09T10:10:00Z";
time=Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", b1)
// get epoch milis
epoch_milis = time.getTime()
log.info("Current date in the specified format:>>>>>>>>>>>> " + epoch_milis);
```

[image]

Please check if this helps.

Also, it is recommended to use JSR223 instead of beanshell due to performance.

Comment: I tried this and it works fine if the ISO timestamp doesn't have any millisecond.
I mean if the timestamp is like "2019-06-19T09:42:48.490Z" then this is not being converted.
Please suggest here if the timestamp has milliseconds too.

Comment: Change the parsing format time like Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", b1)   . Also, you can consider @cfrick answer which is a direct conversion.

Answer (score 3):

This is the format `Instant` can directly parse:

```
java.time.Instant.parse('2018-10-09T10:10:00Z').toEpochMilli()
// => 1539079800000
```

Comment: Thanks for the direct conversion info.